# How to tell whether a Python function with dependencies has changed?

Tags: python, function, caching, introspection, memoization

### tl;dr:

How can I cache the results of a Python function to disk and in a later session use the cached value if and only if the function code and all of its dependencies are unchanged since I last ran it?

In other words, I want to make a Python caching system that automatically watches out for changed code.

### Background

I am trying to build a tool for automatic memoization of computational results from Python. I want the memoization to persist between Python sessions (i.e. be reusable at a later time in another Python instance, preferrably even on another machine with the same Python version).

Assume I have a Python module `mymodule` with some function `mymodule.func()`. Let's say I already solved the problem of serializing/identifying the function arguments, so we can assume that `mymodule.func()` takes no arguments if it simplifies anything.

Also assume that I guarantee that the function `mymodule.func()` and all its dependencies are deterministic, so `mymodule.func() == mymodule.func()`.

### The task

I want to run the function `mymodule.func()` today and save its results (and any other information necessary to solve this task). When I want the same result at a later time, I would like to load the cached result instead of running `mymodule.func()` again, **but only** if the code in `mymodule.func()` and its dependencies are unchanged.

To simplify things, we can assume that the function is always run in a freshly started Python interpreter with a minimal script like this:

```py
import some_save_function
import mymodule
result = mymodule.func()
some_save_function(result, 'filename')
```

Also, note that I don't want to be overly conservative. It is probably not too hard to use the [modulefinder](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/modulefinder.html) module to find all modules involved when running the first time, and then not use the cache if any module has changed at all. But this defeats my purpose, because in my use case it is very likely that some unrelated function in an imported module has changed.

### Previous work and tools I have looked at

- [joblib](https://github.com/joblib/joblib) memoizes results tied to the function name, and also saves the source code so we can check if it is unchanged. However, as far as I understand it does not check upstream functions (called by `mymodule.func()`).
- The [ast](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html?highlight=ast#module-ast) module gives me the Abstract Syntax Tree of any Python code, so I guess I can (in principle) figure it all out that way. How hard would this be? I am not very familiar with the AST.
- Can I use any of all the black magic that's going on inside [dill](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill)?
- More trivia than a solution: [IncPy](http://www.pgbovine.net/incpy.html), a finished/deceased research project, implemented a Python interpreter doing this by default, always. Nice idea, but never made it outside the lab.

Grateful for any input!

Comment: have you succeeded finding the answers? I've been building a similar tool for myself.

Comment: I mas making memoization based of function code, args, closure and nested calls. The problem so far is that when I run the function again, and want to check the nested calls, I have to import them another time, which takes some noteable time, and then their closures are different from when they're "naturally" imported. This means I either can't track them, or I track them, but changing global things like settings will not trigger them to re-run.

Comment: No, I have still not solved this one, but I did start working on my own solution a bit. The path I started on was a static code analysis, wihch might miss some edge cases, but surely avoids any problems associated with side effects of imports etc. Plus, not  even tracking imports with importlib etc will be able to catch all possible edge cases.

Some interesting tools I considered using are:
vulture https://bitbucket.org/jendrikseipp/vulture
pylint https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint
pyflakes https://github.com/PyCQA/pyflakes

Comment: I tried using the globals/closures approach, and turned out when you import and decorate stuff on the way, things change between restarts, between the beginning and the end of a function, and even inside the calls tree. So probably makes sense to just use code + explicitly watched variables and external files, if they are read.

Comment: Another option would be making the memoizer/watcher decorator picky, and raise exceptions if a function that you decorate with it depends on closure vars. `raise OperationalError("Give me functions without side effects!")`